# How to make Vite output "main.js", not "main.jsx" in development?

Tags: reactjs, flask, vite

I am trying to integrate Vite (React) with my Flask backend.

I am following the docs:

https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html

and understand how it should be done for production, but have some problems in dev setup. Namely, the docs say to include the Vite's assets in my backend HTML template like so:

```
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/main.js"></script>
```

but the problem is that in dev mode Vite never generates `main` file in  ".js" format, it is always ".jsx".

That is why - I **suppose** - I get a "not found" error in my browser:

[image]

I followed the docs strictly. Is there anything else I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, so I have watched the HTML of a "standard" react SPA served by Vite server before that it was handled by react, the result is this:

```
<html>
<script type="module">
    import RefreshRuntime from 'http://localhost:5173/@react-refresh'
    RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window)
    window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {}
    window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type
    window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true
  </script>
<!-- if development -->
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/@vite/client"></script>
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/src/main.jsx"></script>


<body>
    <p>This paragraph is a part of HTML.</p>
    <nav id="root"></nav>
    <p>This paragraph is also a part of HTML.</p>
</body>
```

in this way you keep jsx version and the react engine takes care to convert it in js.
Watch out to replace "http://localhost:5173/" with your Vite dev URL.
I hope this will help.